# Calling Async method in class constructor in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sqlite, windows-phone-8

Currently I'm developing an universal app using c#.

In app I used sqlite as database and as you may now It has async methods.

I have a class with some null property that I'll fill them using data I fetch from db, but It should be done exactly in class constructor.

The problem is that using async methods is not allowed, So I tried creating a new async method and using sqlite methods and filling properties in it to call it synchronously in constructor, but as may expecting It doesn't work well.

How can I use async method in class constructor in a way to get data from db and fill class properties right in class constructor method?

Update: Notice that I'm not asking about could it be done or no, I want to init my class vars with data coming from db when the class constructed

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.  Did you get an error message?  What is it?

Comment: No I'm not getting an error, actually I get nothing or null

Answer (score 9):

## Don't do that

Constructors should be simply that: constructors. Move complex initializations to an initialize method.

Constructors have a limited ability to fail gracefully, so don't do anything complicated, long-running, or fragile in them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: thanks for the link! I still think this is a bad idea ;)

Comment: A.Lowe: dear I've already mentioned that I've done your suggestion but It doesn't work as expected

Comment: @RaminMT: i think you misunderstood: I recommend that you *do not do this from the constructor*

Comment: I get what you mean, but I think this is what we call it "construct"!!!

Comment: @RaminMT: the purpose of a constructor is to create the object; trivial initialization is okay because it can't fail. Don't do anything in a constructor that can fail, because there is no way to recover.